# How to emulate mouse position in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, hover, mouse

I'm trying to figure a lot of hover/mouseover related CSS/Javascript on a webpage.
To do so, I use Firefox+firebug inspectors.

The problem, is that whenever I move the mouse out of an element I'm inspecting, all the "hover reactions" are lost.
Is there a way, to fix the mouse position firefox sees so I can freely use the mouse withouth concern about weiter it actually hovers some elements or not?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is not fixing the mouse position, but when you right-click on an element in the Inspector in the regular Developer Tools, you're offered a `:hover` menu item (along some other things). Selecting that will put the element into permanent `:hover` state. That at least should cover the CSS-part of your question.  I'm sure Firebug offers something similar.

[image: Context menu]

For the JS-part, I'd just set a breakpoint somewhere.